# Where to find com.drew jar for Java?

Tags: java

I am not able to find any place from where I can get

```
com.drew.*
```

I searched for its jar but didn't succeed actually.
Due to this, I am unable to resolve the error:

```
The import com.drew cannot be resolved
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance..

**EDIT:**

THere is a jar dependency version mismatch issue with my application.. any suggestions on getting the whole list of jar versions corresponding to this class?

Comment: What are you trying to get from there?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/2.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here maybe? http://www.findjar.com/jar/com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/2.4.0-beta-1/metadata-extractor-2.4.0-beta-1.jar.html?all=true

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [findjar.com](http://findjar.com/index.x) for such things.

An example result for com.drew:
http://www.findjar.com/class/com/drew/lang/Rational.html